# Angular2 - http call Code coverage

Tags: http, angular, jasmine, code-coverage, istanbul

My components.ts is,

```
 getHomePageData() : void{
    this.homeservice.getHomePageData()
          .subscribe(
              data =>   {

                            //console.log("response status ################### "+data.status);
                            //console.log("getUserData response ************ \n"+JSON.stringify(data));
                            this.defaultFacilityId = data.response.defaultFacilityId;
                            this.defaultFacilityName = data.response.defaultFacilityName;
                            this.enterpriseId = data.response.enterpriseId;
                            this.enterpriseName = data.response.enterpriseName;
                            this.facilityList = data.response.facilityList;
                            this.userName = data.response.userName;

                            this.showDefaultPopoup();
                        },
              error =>  {
                            console.error(error);
                            //this.errorMessage="Technical error - Contact Support team !" ;
                        }
          );

  }
```

So my component.spec.ts is ,

```
 it('getHomePageData with SUCCESS - getHomePageData()', () => {
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      //expect(connection.request.url).toEqual('http://localhost:8080/MSMTestWebApp/UDM/UdmService/Home/');
      expect(connection.request.url).toEqual('http://192.168.61.158:9080/GetUserData');

      expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Get);
      expect(connection.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqual('application/json');
      let options = new ResponseOptions({
        body:
        {
          "request": { "url": "/getUserData" },
          "response": {
                 "defaultFacilityName":"3M Health Information Systems",
                  "enterpriseId":"11.0",
                  "enterpriseName":"HSA Enterprise",
                  "defaultFacilityId": "55303.0",
                  "userName":"Anand"
          },
          "error": ""
        },
        status : 200
      });

      connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));

    });

     backend.connections.subscribe((data) => {
      //expect(data.response.facilityId).toEqual("55303.0");
      //expect(subject.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })

    service.getHomePageData().subscribe((data) => {
          //expect(videos.length).toBe(4);
          expect(data.response.defaultFacilityId).toEqual("55303.0");
          component.defaultFacilityId = data.response.defaultFacilityId;
          component.defaultFacilityName = data.response.defaultFacilityName;
          component.enterpriseId = data.response.enterpriseId;
          component.enterpriseName = data.response.enterpriseName;
          component.userName = data.response.userName;
          console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$**********$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
      });

  });
```

When i try to run test case. It got passed. But while I look into the code coverage, it doesn't cover the code shown in red below[image]

Please help to get the full code coverage. Thanks.

Comment: Something wrong with your example. Can you add `TestBed.configureTestingModule` section? How many assertions has test when it got passed? Did you tried to add `async` / `fakeAsync` to test?

Comment: @HumanBeing Could you provide coverage config, what did you use angular-cli or custom webpack config ?

Answer (score 6):

In the test you've shown here you don't seem to be calling `getHomePageData()` from your component

Try building your test like this:

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
...
it('getHomePageData with SUCCESS - getHomePageData()', fakeAsync(() => {
  backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
  //expect(connection.request.url).toEqual('http://localhost:8080/MSMTestWebApp/UDM/UdmService/Home/');
  expect(connection.request.url).toEqual('http://192.168.61.158:9080/GetUserData');

  expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Get);
  expect(connection.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqual('application/json');
  let options = new ResponseOptions({
    body:
    {
      "request": { "url": "/getUserData" },
      "response": {
             "defaultFacilityName":"3M Health Information Systems",
              "enterpriseId":"11.0",
              "enterpriseName":"HSA Enterprise",
              "defaultFacilityId": "55303.0",
              "userName":"Anand"
      },
      "error": ""
    },
    status : 200
  });

  connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));

  });

  // If this function is not automatically called in the component initialisation
  component.getHomePageData();
  tick();
  //you can call expects on your component's properties now
  expect(component.defaultFacilityId).toEqual("55303.0");

});
```

`FakeAsync` allows you to write tests in a more linear style so you no longer have to subscribe to the service function to write your expectations.

In a `FakeAsync` test function you can call `tick()` after a call where an asynchronous operation takes place to simulate a passage of time and then continue with the flow of your code.

You can read more about this here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/#!#fake-async

**EDIT - Error Case**

To test the error logic you can call `mockError` or set up an error response using `mockRespond` on your connection:

```
it('getHomePageData with ERROR- getHomePageData()', fakeAsync(() => {
  backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    if (connection.request.url === 'http://192.168.61.158:9080/GetUserData') {
        // mockError option
        connection.mockError(new Error('Some error'));
        // mockRespond option
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
          status: 404,
          statusText: 'URL not Found',
        })));
    }

  component.getHomePageData();
  tick();
  //you can call expects now
  expect(connection.request.url).toEqual('http://192.168.61.158:9080/GetUserData');
  expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Get);
  expect(connection.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqual('application/json');
  expect('you can test your error logic here');
});
```

What we're doing inside the subscription is making sure that anytime the `GetUserData` endpoint is called within this test method it will return an error.

Because we test errors and successes separately in the success test there's no need to add the error related settings in the request options.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer... Coverage for **success case** is fine . Now the code coverage need to be covered for **error** case ? Can u please help me ?

Comment: No worries, I've edited the answer to add the error situation

Answer (score 2):

Are you using JSON data? Then you should probably use `map()` before using `.subscribe().`

```
.map((res:Response) => res.json())
```

Try organizing your code like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getHomePageData();
}

getHomePageData() {
 this.http.get('your.json')
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => { 
      this.YourData = data
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('ok')
  );
}
```

Hope it helps,

Cheers

Comment: I am using the **map** in the **service.ts** .  In the **component.ts**  I cannot use **map** function.

Comment: I think it is woth giving it a try. Otherwise, try to get your data where you use map, service.ts.

Comment: In **service.ts** Ivan able to cover 100 percentage coverage. Both success and failure case. Here in **component.ts** , may be **subscribe** creates problems.